# Import error in Python 3.6 with sudo?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, sudoers

I have written a program that uses `Scapy`. `Python` is able to import the `scapy` module perfectly but using `sniff` function of `scapy` requires running the program as administrator.
However, running the program as `sudo python3 <program_name>` produces an `import error`, why is it so?

Here is the import line : `import scapy.all as scapy`

Comment: If you install and use scapy within a virtualenv does this still happen? So: 
`virtualenv -p $(which python) venv`
`source venv/bin/activate`
`pip install scapy`
And then run your code from within the virtualenv

Comment: @Arnoux I've tried virtualenv, the error is still there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As using python3, I would recommend

```
sudo python3 -m pip install scapy
```

Of course pyenv works too I'd you're familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with:

```
$ sudo pip install scapy
```

And then try again.

I would recommend using `virtualenv` to run your program though. Instead of installing package after package in your main environment.

Comment: With `sudo pip install scapy` this is what I get : `The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.` Also, tried virtualenv, the error is still there.